# i want to make a alarm manager ...can any one help me with a specific code please?

Tags: android

I want to make a alarmmanager, in which u can set only one alarm and delete it.

Here is my code. It's not working.actually when i'm setting the alarm it;s showing that the alarm is set..but it's not giving any notification or response...i want to set only one alarm at a time and delete it.. What i need to change here..can anyone help pls????

This is my main class. i have two more classes which are called database AlarmReceiver

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TimePicker myTimePicker;
Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView textAlarmPrompt;
int i=0;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
String show="";
int RQS_1;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
String minute,hour,purpose;
TextView test;

EditText et1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPurpose);
    test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);

        }});

}


private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            MainActivity.this, 
            onTimeSetListener, 
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
            is24r);
            purpose = et1.getText().toString();
            hour = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            minute = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            /*database ob1 = new database(this);

            ob1.Open();
            ob1.insert(purpose, hour, minute);
            ob1.Close();*/
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

    timePickerDialog.show();

}

OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
= new OnTimeSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
            //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        setAlarm(calSet);
    }};

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){




    show = show + "\n\n\n"
            + "Alarm is set at " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
            + "\n";
    textAlarmPrompt.setText(show);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("msg", "This is Activated");



        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);



        i++;

}
public void resetClicked(View aview)
    {
        deleteAlarm();
    }

    private void deleteAlarm() 
    {
        int p=0;
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), alarmRemove.class);
        pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0, intent, 0);*/

        //alarmManager.cancel(intentArray.get(1));
        //et1.setText(Integer.toString(intentArray.size()));    


    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is there a crash, if yes please post the logcat and be more specific.

Comment: it's not crashing..alarm is setting..but it's not giving the notification that alarm is received

Comment: Please specify (by editing the question) "not working". What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code doesn't make any sense. You're launching the alarm receiver when you're setting the alarm. First, that's not how you trigger a broadcast receiver, and second, even if you could trigger it that way, launching the alarm when it's first being set makes no sense.

Please read more about [Broadcast Receivers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html). Someone could give you the code and you could cut and paste it into your project, but that's not the way to learn.

If you're going to get anywhere, you should first learn about the fundamentals first.